# using gnu global in vim with file/folder name contains space

Tags: vim, cscope

I have used gnu global tags (a tag system like cscope) to trace my c/cpp code for a long time, however, I encounter a problem when there are spaces in folder/file name.

For example, in my project pj1, I use "`:cs f s foo`" to find all "`foo`":

`pj1/s pace.cpp` and `pj1/ok.cpp` both have a `foo()` function:

```
int foo()
{
}
```

vim will open a list like that:

```
Cscope tag: foo                                            
   #   line  filename / context / line
   1      1  ok.cpp <<foo>>
             int foo()
   2      1  s%20pace.cpp <<foo>>
             int foo()
```

notice that the space have been converted to "`%20`", so when I choose 2 to open the location, it will get an error:

> E429: File "s%20pace.cpp" does not exist

anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Spaces in paths just don't play well in Vim (or in many non-graphical tools).